# By comparing dimensions, show that in general a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ has all its values zero if and only if it is divisible by $f_0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

**Problem:**

> Let $\mathbb{F}_p = \mathbb{Z}/p$ denote the field with $p$ elements, and let $V_d \subset \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ be the space of polynomials of degree at most $d$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_p$. Consider the evaluation map
> $$\begin{align*} \phi_d : V_d &\to (\mathbb{F}_p)^p \\\\ 
> f &\mapsto (f(0), f(1), . . . , f(p − 1)). \end{align*}$$
> a)  Find explicitly a generator of $\text{Ker}(\phi_p)$; that is, a nonzero polynomial $f_0 \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ of degree at most $p$ whose values are identically zero.
> b) By comparing dimensions, show that in general a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ has all its values zero if and only if it is divisible by $f_0$.

**My work:**

For the first part just take the generator $$f_0 = \prod^{p-1}_{j=0} (x-j)$$
Now, my doubt is how can I answer the second part by comparing dimensions? I was able to find an answer just by using the division algorithm for polynomials but I would like to know how to prove it in the way it is asked.

I would appreciate any hints, thanks in advance.

Comment: b) For any $d\ge p$, compare the dimensions of $\ker(\phi_d)$ and its subspace $V_{d-p}f_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$V_d$ has dimension $d+1$, and $f$ is a polynomial of degree $p$.

If $d < p$, then $\phi_d$ is injective as a polynomial with $p$ roots must have degree at least $p$.

Additionally, if $d \geq p - 1$. Given $(x_1, ... x_p) \in (\mathbb{F}_p)^p$  We can use Lagrange interpolation to find a polynomial of degree $p-1$ that has all those points. Thus, $\phi_d$ is surjective.  (The situation where both cases apply is if $d = p-1$, in which case $\phi_d$ is an isomorphism).

Now, we use the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow ker(\phi_d) \rightarrow V_d \rightarrow (\mathbb{F}_p)^p \rightarrow 0$ to find the dimension of $ker(\phi_d)$. We get $d + 1 - p$.

A polynomial that is a multiple of $f_0$ is in $ker(\phi_d)$ and is of the form $f_0 g$, where $g$ is an arbitrary polynomial. If $g$ has degree $d$, then $f_0 g$ has degree $d + p$. Therefore, the space of degree $d$ polynomials that are a multiple of $f_0$ is $d - p + 1$.

This is the same dimension as that of $ker(\phi_d)$, so we are done.

Comment: Your short exact sequence is just the rank-nullity theorem, right? Is there a general rank-nullity theorem involving exact sequences? I’d appreciate a reference. +1

Comment: @Fshrike The first isomorphism theorem.